# Setup a headless device to connect to a wifi network

Tags: android, wifi, iot, chromecast

I have a device with no screen + a microcontroller + a wifi module.

So far so good but basically I'd like to setup my device so it can connect to a wifi network, so I made an app to do that.

The strategy is:

- put the device in wifi AP mode with a custom ssid like "Device XXXX"
- connect to this ssid "Device XXXX"
- Ask the user for its home wifi credentials
- send the credentials to the device (for example using http) -> `POST http://x.x.x.x/wifi_creds "Home" "homepassword"`
- poll the device to check whether it could connect to the "Home" network -> `GET http://x.x.x.x/conn_status`
- Once it's connected, stop the AP mode -> `POST http://x.x.x.x/wifi_ap_mode 0`

This works pretty well, but it requires the user to manually connect to the "Device XXXX" ssid.
And actually on Android I can make things even easier by connecting automatically to this ssid, but I need to find the ssid first.

So my idea was to scan all the ssids and to connect to the first one that matches the pattern `/^Device [0-9a-zA-Z]{4}/` (like Device 1234).

However this doesn't look like a good way to find a hotspot, and there might be a better way.
Also, I don't want to give it a default name as it could conflict with another ssid.

Is there another way to find my device (or my device ssid) without this trick?

I know that Google home is able to connect to a Chromecast allowing you to configure it while the Chromecast is in AP mode with a ssid that looks like "Chromecast XXXX" (**when the bluetooth is disabled**), and I'm not sure how they do it

Comment: Did you look at [Wi-Fi P2P](https://developer.android.com/training/connect-devices-wirelessly/wifi-direct)(Wi-Fi Direct™, not to be confused with ad-hoc network) ?

Answer (score -2):

***I've assumed (perhaps wrongly) that your headless device is Android based. If it is Android and has Bluetooth, specifically Bluetooth Low Energy and is above Android 5.0:**

You could get the device to act as a Bluetooth beacon which constantly broadcasts it's SSID.

So your app first scans for Bluetooth beacons - the beacon payload could be any arbitrary data - perhaps some known hard coded GUID to be sure you're talking to the correct Bluetooth beacon and also embed the SSID.

Now go and scan for the SSID and connect to it.

See this [library](https://altbeacon.github.io/android-beacon-library/beacon-transmitter.html) for details on how to do this.

I believe you can even configure a kind of 'geofence' so that as soon as you come into range of the beacon your app wakes up and does the pairing.